# Adjusting Antenna Range using Motorola Emdks

Tags: c#, motorola-emdk

using the following code;I am trying to adjust the range for my antennas;

```
Antennas.Config config = new Antennas.Config();
config.TransmitPowerIndex = (ushort)myreader.TransmitPowerIndex;
config.TransmitFrequencyIndex = (ushort)myreader.TransmitFrequencyIndex;
config.ReceiveSensitivityIndex = (ushort)myreader.ReceiveSensitivityIndex;
myreader.ReaderAPI.Config.Antennas.SetConfig(config);
```

The problem is, it wont let me change `TransmitPowerIndex` or `ReceiveSensitivityIndex` 
apart from 0, the exception I get is "config value of out range"

If I run the antennas at default settings (without using the code above), they run at full power.

If I use the following settings:

```
Antennas.Config config = new Antennas.Config();
config.TransmitPowerIndex = 10;
config.TransmitFrequencyIndex = 1;
config.ReceiveSensitivityIndex = 0;
myreader.ReaderAPI.Config.Antennas.SetConfig(config);
```

Antennas run at a significantly low power,but this is too low for mysetting,If I want to change the powerindex to 20 for example,nothing changes.If I change the transmitfrequencyindex or the receivesensitivityindex to anything other than the values above,i get "config value out of range error".

How can I adjust the range of my antennas, based on some values on a linear basis? EMDK help files have no certain data on that unfortunately...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a little late, but better than never.

Motorola uses a table to assign the power of the antennas. This table is located in this property:

```
Symbol.RFID3.Reader MyReader;

int[] table = MyReader.ReaderCapabilities.TransmitPowerLevelValues;
```

Now, table is an array of int, the values are the power levels available for the antenna.

For example, let's assume **table** contains 50 items.

If you want the antenna at 50%:

```
config.TransmitPowerIndex = 24;
```

If you want the antenna at ~75%:

```
config.TransmitPowerIndex = 36;
```

If you want the antenna at 100%:

```
config.TransmitPowerIndex = 49;
```

Remember, you have to assign the **INDEX** of the value you want.

Hope this helps somebody.
Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Antenna Read Range is set by `config.TransmitPowerIndex`

Then for Maximum Read Range:

```
config.TransmitPowerIndex = 160;
```

For Minimum Read Range:

```
config.TransmitPowerIndex = 0;
```